# plot multiple data with plot over line in python

Tags: python, plot, vtk, paraview

I am reading an insight case.

for a certain slice, I am plotting between two points with the next plot overline function :

```
def plotoverline(Xa,Ya,Xb,Yb,Za,Zb,case,index):

    PlotOverLine1 = PlotOverLine( Source = "High Resolution Line Source" )

    PlotOverLine1.Source.Point1 = [Xa, Ya, Za]
    PlotOverLine1.Source.Point2 = [Xb, Yb, Zb]

    PlotOverLine1.Source.Resolution = nb_pts

    # saving data in CSV File
    filename = "case_" + str(case) + "_"  + str(index) + ".csv"
    writer = CreateWriter(filename)
    writer.FieldAssociation = "Points" # or "Cells"
    writer.UpdatePipeline() 

return filename
```

I want to plot multiple lines and export every line's data to a `csv` file, but my code only writes the data of the first line and "nan" for the other lines.

```
Z = 200 # attitude of my slice
for i in range(le):
    Xb = left[i,0]
    Yb = left[i,1]
    Xa = pt[i,0] 
    Ya = pt[i,1] 
    data = plotoverline(Xa,Ya,Xb,Yb,Z,Z,case,ind_left[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to specify wich slice I am working on : the plotoverline function becomes :

```
def plotoverline(Slice, Xa,Ya,Xb,Yb,Za,Zb,case,index):

    SetActiveSource(Slice)
    PlotOverLine1 = PlotOverLine( Source = "High Resolution Line Source" )

    PlotOverLine1.Source.Point1 = [Xa, Ya, Za]
    PlotOverLine1.Source.Point2 = [Xb, Yb, Zb]

    PlotOverLine1.Source.Resolution = nb_pts

    # saving data in CSV File
    filename = "case_" + str(case) + "_"  + str(index) + ".csv"
    writer = CreateWriter(filename)
    writer.FieldAssociation = "Points" # or "Cells"
    writer.UpdatePipeline() 

return filename
```